# copy NSData into int32_t variable

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdictionary

I have a big NSDictionary full of entries that are all of type NSData. I have several entries that need to be of type int32_t however I am not 100% sure how to copy the data in the entries of the NSDictionary across..

is it as simple as doing the following -

***.h***

```
//..
int32_t myint;
}
@property (assign) int32_t myint;
//..
```

***.m***

```
//..
@synthesize cardID;
//..
- (void)assignSearchData:(NSData*)searchData
{
myint = [searchData objectForKey:@"IntKey"];
}
//..
```

or do I need some type of data conversion inside my method?

and a quick side question, have I even declared the int32_t correctly? I have looked for an example in the docs and on here but am struggling to find one.

Comment: `NSData` doesn't respond to `objectForKey:` did you mean to declare an `NSDictionary` parameter?

Comment: opps yes NSDictionary is what I was meaning, it contains entries of NSData.. thats where I got confused, I'll fix my question so its abit more readable

Comment: Thanks for the help guys I am very sorry for the accidental issue of it not being NSData. The silver lining of it all is that I have learn abit about passing NSData to int32_t objects :).. so now Im going to go off an find out how to convert NSString to int32_t

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can access the raw bytes in the data object directly.

```
void const *dataPtr = [data bytes];
```

Now that you have a pointer to raw memory, you can copy it any way you want (these rules apply to any data transfer, not just iOS).  If you need to consider alignment boundaries, you need to use memcpy.

```
int32_t myInt;
memcpy(&myInt, dataPtr);
```

Otherwise, if on an architecture that allows integer manipulation across alignment boundaries...

```
int32_t myInt = *(int32_t const *)dataPtr;
```

Now, ARM supports access across alignment boundaries, but it's much slower.  I have not done a performance comparison, but you are not continuing to use the mal-alignged pointer, so it may be better than the memcpy function call (though, to be honest, that is probably way too much performance consideration for you).

The biggest concern is byte-order of the data.  If it's provided by you, then do whatever you want, but you should prefer one standard.

If it's coming from a third party, it's probably in network byte order (aka big-endian).  You may need to convert to your host endian representation.  Fortunately, that's straight forward with `hton` and `ntoh` and their friends.

FWIW, Intel is little-endian, and network-byte-order is big-endian, modern Macs and iOS devices are little-endian, older Macs are big-endian.

```
// Convert from network order to host order.
// Does the right thing wherever your code is running
myInt = ntohl(myInt);
```

In short, either...

```
int32_t myInt = ntohl(*(int32_t const *)[data bytes]);
```

or

```
int32_t myInt;
memcpy(&myInt, [data bytes);
myInt = ntohl(myInt);
```

So, the data has to get in there somehow.  It's, the inverse...

```
int32_t myInt = 42;
myInt = htonl(myInt);
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:&myInt length:sizeof(myInt) freeWhenDone:NO];
```

Of course, use the right Data initializer... that one will just use those raw bytes on the stack, so you better not use it after the stack unwinds.

You don't have to worry about alignment on the data you send, unless you are guaranteeing the receiver that the data will be aligned to some boundary.

Comment: as soon as I try to use memcpy in any of these examples the app falls over and gives this error

 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2002c4f0'

Comment: That error means you are sending the message "bytes" to a NSString, and NSString does not implement that method.  So, even though you may have your object as "Data*" it's really a "NSString*"  Are you sure you are supposed to be processing a NSData object and not a NSString object?  They are two completely different, unrelated, classes.

Comment: yep... jesus.. I think maybe the entries in my NSDictionary are now strings and not data... its been so long since I made the dictionary maybe I have confused it with something else I have done.. and instead of checking ... I have made a grave mistake.. going to check it now and report back with my findings.......

Comment: okay so I am receiving a bunch of binary data back from the server, I parse though it to get to the xml which is still in a data format.. But I think when I pass it over to the parser thats when the values get converted into what i guess are string values. Im not sure because this method I used is pretty ambiguous, **- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict** I should have looked further into this, but this is where my data is becoming a string..

Comment: Well, NSString has accessor methods to convert the string into various number types: doubleValue, floatValue, intValue, integerValue, longLongValue, boolValue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, int32_t is fine. So you have a stream of byes. What you need to know is what he layout of the bytes are. It you know what the data is it will be pretty easy to construct it.

Given a NSData object with a length of 4 (size of int32_t), then you would :

```
int32_t val;
if([data length] == sizeof(uint32_t)) {
    void *bytes = [data bytes];
    // if the layout is same as iOS then
    memcpy(&val, bytes, sizeof(int32_t) );
}
```

if that is not the case, then you can try:

```
unsigned char val[4] = {0,0,0,0};
if([data length] == sizeof(uint32_t)) {
    memcpy(val, bytes, sizeof(int32_t) );
    then rearrange the bytes
}
```

Comment: okay cool, I am going to give them both a try now :) thanks for the quick response, will let you know how i get on.

Comment: I have a warning while trying to use the void *bytes = [data bytes]; which says **Initializing 'void *' with an expression of type 'const void *' discards qualifiers** not sure how to handle this.

Comment: Yeah, that's because [NSData bytes] returns a "void const *" which means it points to data that it does not want you to mess with.  Change it to "void const *bytes = [data bytes]"

Comment: @JodyHagins thanks - what that warning meant was the variable declaration should have said "You are not permitted to WRITE through this pointer!"

Comment: okay right.. Its interesting because with Jody's solution I get a critical failure on the line where I perform the memcpy.. not sure if its something I have done or not.. I am just reading Jody's solution now and going to try it out.. see how it goes.

Comment: the data I get back can vary in size, I can get back values like '1' or '55'  etc so the if statement is never entered.  also in your first example I think **data length comparison needs to be in brackets. I tried your solution outside of the if statement and I still crashing the app :( I'm about to try the second solution you provided even though I dont understand the need for the char, however I think it has something to do with the 32bit int sizing (or initalization or something)

Comment: I had done pseudocode not real code - I didn't test it in a real system. The idea is to first test the size of the data, and if its the size of a uint32_t then you can copy it. If its 3 or 2 or 1 then you have to know how that data is packed. This idea of putting an integer into a NSData object is quite odd and non-standard and I'm totally perplexed why that happened. A much more common technique would be to use NSNumber objects, or even NSValue objects.