# How do i properly ensure 32 and 64 Bit compatibility?

Tags: ios, objective-c

More of a general question regarding the 32 to 64 bit step we had a few years ago.

Assume we have an app that saves something to disk and this can be sent to others. It could be sent from 32bit system and read on 64bit and vice versa.

If i write stuff to disk with

`[NSData dataWithBytes:&thedata length:sizeof(long)];`

On 32bit the sizeof will be 4 and on 64bit it will be 8. Once written to disk it is 'written-down-bytes' and the other side will read it in its own length.

To ensure that it works i would have to cast it all down to primitives that are/will be consistent in length.

I understand that if i use `NSInteger`it will not be the case as with all typedefs that could be conditional. But even primitives are not safe. `int`and `float`are for now but `long` did change. How can i ensure that i work with primitives that STAY safe ?

Who knows what the future might bring...

so what is the best tactic to battle this ?

Comment: "In the rare case where an application wants to read 64-bit values in 32-bit processes, it can use `decodeInt64ForKey:` and be explicit about the type rather than using `decodeIntegerForKey:` (which reads back 32-bit on 32-bit systems)." https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/ConvertingExistingApp/ConvertingExistingApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004247-CH5-SW1

Comment: what if the app does not know what system it was written by ? all it has is a file

Comment: You need to write the system identifier into the stream of data;  and likely also an archive version #.   Really, I'd recommend you don't invent a new data format unless you really need to.  Use NSArchiver or CoreData or property lists, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way of making sure this doesn't come back to bite you is to not do it.

As a *very* general rule of thumb, if something is held in a POD (i.e. an `NSInteger`, an `int64_t`, a `float`, ...) it should never be written to disk or packed into `NSData` directly.

The simplest way to go about it for your use case is probably to stick your `NSInteger` in an `NSNumber` (using `NSNumber`'s `+numberWithInteger:`), and then sticking that in an `NSDictionary`, and then reading and writing that with `+dictionaryWithContentsOfURL` and `-writeToURL:atomically:`.

If you absolutely need it in `NSData`, there's a trick for that as well:

```
NSData *myData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:aDictionary];

NSDictionary *anotherDictionary =
  (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:myData];
```

By this method, you'll be (relatively) assured that your number survives unscathed, no matter what system it gets sent to.

Comment: why would it be safe in a dictionary ? what's the reasoning behind that ?

Comment: @NikkyD Well, really it's NSNumber that makes it safe. You could do all of the above just using an NSNumber. The reason for that is that when stuff like NSKeyedCoding, NSNumber and NSDictionary was developed, the developers thought of all the problems that go into different widths (maybe with 16 and 32 at the time, I suppose); different endianness, sizes of bytes, and all the other plumbing stuff, so you don't have to.

Comment: @NikkyD Basically, the Cocoa APIs guarantee that an `NSNumber` written to a well-defined format (e.g. the format produced by `NSPropertyListSerialization`, or by `NSKeyedArchiver`) will be read in exactly the same way on other versions of the OS, platforms, etc. Instead of doing the work and creating a new archive format (as bbum mentioned in a comment on your question), you can use the work that Apple has done to ensure the same effects.

Comment: @ItaiFerber And NeXT. Don't forget NeXT. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you need to guarantee that the length equals on 32 and 64 bit systems, you can use the specific types `int32_t`, `int64_t` ...

How to convert this to byte arrays / `NSData` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11874713/1457385).

Comment: The first part of your question is misleading, and exactly what NikkyD is trying to avoid: if you encode an `NSInteger` on a 64-bit system, it will write out 64 bits worth of data; if you read that as an `NSInteger` on a 32-bit system, it will only read 32 bits. (And vice versa.) This is the same problem as using `long`.